# How to check if iPhone has dual camera?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing a photo app and I need different overlays in the camera view for iPhones with dual camera (to account for the zoom ui), is there a proper way to check if a dual camera exists?

I tried to get the device and check if it was nil for the non dual camera iPhones, tho it still retunes a device:

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInDualCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back)
```

Dose anyone know how to detect the dual camera?

Comment: this is a proper way to check it, what's the problem ?

Comment: What does it return when the phone doesn't have a dual camera? Should return `nil`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 5**:

```
var currentDevice:AVCaptureDevice?

     if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) {

                currentDevice = device

         } else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) {

                currentDevice = device

            } else {

                print("Error: no camera available")
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as the apple's example:

```
if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInDuoCamera,
                                                  mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                  position: .back) {
        return device
    } else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera,
                                                  mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                  position: .back) {
        return device
    } else {
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

to support triple-camera

```
    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice?
    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTripleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) {
        captureDevice = device
    }
    else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) {
        captureDevice = device
    }
    else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) {
        captureDevice = device
    }
```